# Return customized json in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm building a Rails API and using Devise for user model and authentication.

For the user registration, some of the users forget to add "Content-Type application/json" to the header. Hence create action gives "422 Unprocessable Entity" error from the console side.

But users only see email and password can't be blank error, even though they post those variables.

I would like to change the error message, or at least add one more sentence saying that don't forget to add content-type headers.

That would be great if you can help me.

Thanks!